# How can I transform a column to a table in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a column:

```
Column
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
...
```

I want it to be transformed into:

```
Column1    Column2
1.1        1.2
1.3        1.4
...
```

The only way I can think of is:
Add index column-> Extract even rows-> Extract odd rows-> Filter rows-> Merge them
But is there any faster and simpler way to do it?

Comment: sebastian! has the problem been solved?

Answer (score 2):

Do these steps in `power query`

- Insert index from 0
- calculate `modulo` by 2
- calculate integer division by 2 (on index again)
- remove index
- pivot (don't aggregate)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I provide this answer as an alternative slightly different of what you're mentionning as the steps to the solution (couldn't replicate yours though).

Steps are renamed so you may follow what's being done.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    RemoveAlternateUneven = Table.AlternateRows(Source,0,1,1),
    AddIndexUneven = Table.AddIndexColumn(RemoveAlternateUneven, "Índice", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    RemoveAlternateEven = Table.AlternateRows(Source,1,1,1),
    AddIndexEven = Table.AddIndexColumn(RemoveAlternateEven, "Índice", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    MergeQueries = Table.NestedJoin(AddIndexEven, {"Índice"}, AddIndexUneven, {"Índice"}, "Índice agregado1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandQuery = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeQueries, "Índice agregado1", {"Column"}, {"Column.1"}),
    RemoveIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(ExpandQuery,{"Índice"})
in
    RemoveIndex
```